# RMYSQL Writetable error

Tags: r, dataframe, rmysql

I have the following R dataframe

```
 Sl NO  Name    Marks
 1        A      15
 2        B      20
 3        C      25
```

I have a mysql table as follows. (Score.table)

```
   No   CandidateName   Score
   1       AA           1
   2       BB           2
   3       CC           3
```

I have written my dataframe to Score.table using this code

```
    username='username'
    password='userpass'
    dbname='cdb'
    hostname='***.***.***.***'

    cdbconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user=username, password=userpass, 
    dbname=dbname, host=hostname)
```

Next we write the dataframe to the table as follows

```
     score.table<-'score.table'

    dbWriteTable(cdbconn, score.table, dataframe, append =F, overwrite=T).
```

The code runs and I get TRUE as the output. 
However, when I check the SQL table, the new values haven't overwritten the existing values.
I request someone to help me. The code works. I have reinstalled the RMySQL package again and rerun and the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That updates are not happening indicates that the `RMySQL` package cannot successfully map any of the rows from your data frame to already existing records in the table.  So this would imply that your call to `dbWriteTable` has a problem.  Two potential problems I see are that you did not assign values for `field.types` or `row.names`.  Consider making the following call:

```
score.table <- 'score.table'
dbWriteTable(cdbconn, score.table, dataframe,
             field.types=list(`Sl NO`="int", Name="varchar(55)", Marks="int"),
             row.names=FALSE)
```

If you omit `field.types`, then the package will try to infer what the types are.  I am not expert with this package, so I don't know how robust this inference is, but most likely you would want to specify explicit types for complex update queries.

The bigger problem might actually be not specifying a value for `row.names`.  It can default to `TRUE`, in which case the package will actually send an *extra* column during the update.  This can cause problems, for example if your target table has three columns, and the data frame also has three columns, then you are trying to update with *four* columns.

Comment: thank you. Is it mandatory we have to specify the field types. Please let me know

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs It is not mandatory, but if my suggestion fixed your problem then it is mandatory for your use case.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeilsen will try the same and let you know. Thank You again

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs Can you get _any_ MySQL operation to work from R?  Select, update, insert, delete?  Can you edit your question and include the full MySQL table definition?  Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE score.table` and paste the output.

Comment: I have run these queries . Insert and truncate work. I do not have access to create the sql table in R

Comment: I'm stumped.  I will leave this answer up until someone gives the real answer.

Comment: It Works. Thank You

Comment: I asked a colleague to take a look as well. We reran the code after clearing R's cache. It works neatly now.